# Flutter table bind List of data

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to bind list of data in flutter Table.

```
  Table TaskTable() {
    return Table(
        defaultColumnWidth: FixedColumnWidth(120.sp),
        border: TableBorder.all(width: 1, color: Color.fromRGBO(221, 221, 221, 1), style: BorderStyle.solid),
        children: <TableRow>[
          //Header
          TableRow(
            children: [
              Text('User'),
              Text('Address'),
              Text('Comment'),
            ]
          ),
          // Need to bind list of Task here
          // inside list like 
          TableRow(
            children: [
              Text('${task[i].user}'),
              Text('${task[i].address}'),
              Text('${task[i].comment}'),
            ]
          ),

  }
```

How could I bind list data with index *i.e task[i].user* after header row.

Answer (score 0):

```
TableRow(
 children: [
   Text('User'),
   Text('Address'),
   Text('Comment'),
  ]
 ),
for (int i=0; i<taskList!.length; i++) TableRow(children: [
    Text('${taskList![i].user}'),
    Text('${taskList![i].address}'),
    Text('${taskList![i].comment}'),
  ]),
```

This is the solution. Now list will bind in Table.